# Can I use the Snowblind Stare spell (from Midgard Heroes Handbook) twice on the same target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was leveling up and found the  *snowblind stare* spell. I thought it would be cool to use, but now I am curious whether I am able to use it on the same person twice to given them both stages of snow blindness, given the fact that its duration is "Concentration, up to 2 rounds".

The [*snowblind stare*](http://kpogl.wikidot.com/spell:snowblind-stare) spell is from [*Midgard Heroes Handbook*](https://koboldpress.com/kpstore/product/midgard-heroes-handbook-for-5th-edition-dnd-5e/) by Kobold Press:

> **Casting Time**: 1 action
> **Range**: Self
> **Components**: V, S
> **Duration**: Concentration, up to 2 rounds
>
> Your eyes burn with a bright, cold light that inflicts snow blindness on a creature you target within 30 feet of you. If the target fails a Constitution saving throw, it suffers the first stage of snow blindness (see Conditions), or the second stage of snow blindness if it already has the first stage. The target recovers as described in Conditions.

The [snow blindness condition](http://kpogl.wikidot.com/conditions) is also from *Midgard Heroes Handbook*

> Snow blindness becomes a danger after 4 hours of exposure to a brightly sunlit snowscape. Starting at the end of the 4th hour of exposure, a character must make a Constitution saving throw at the end of every hour; the DC equals 10 + hours exposed beyond 3 (or, for simplicity, 7 + hours of exposure).
>
> Travelers have devised effective precautions. Characters can avoid making a check by taking a short rest after 3 hours, or by wearing dark goggles or snow visors (similar to goggles but made from an opaque material such as bone with a narrow, horizontal slit instead of tinted lenses). Monsters native to the environment are immune, as are constructs and undead.
>
> Failing the saving throw imposes the first stage of snow blindness: the character has disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight, weapon and spell ranges (for visually targeted spells) are halved, and all attack rolls are made with a –2 penalty. A second failed saving throw brings on the second stage of snow blindness: severe pain in the eyes, sight range is limited to 15 feet, and disadvantage on attack rolls and Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight. Spending two days in a dimly-lit environment reduces snow blindness by one stage. Sight is restored completely by lesser restoration or comparable magic.

Comment: Is your confusion about casting a second concentration spell (you can't), or if the same casting inflicts the second condition on the second round?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't  entirely sure if I continued to stare at them if it would proc again if they failed the first time.

Answer (score 2):

### Inconclusive

The spell description really doesn't say. It has no restrictions for repeated use, but neither does it have any instructions for how to utilize the 2 rounds of concentration. I would have expected it to say that you can use an action on your second turn to attempt to blind a target, but it doesn't. The spell description only ever mentions one target and one attempt at blinding, but the 2 rounds of concentration make no sense if that's the case. If I was the DM I would say yes.